Decomposition of a general (not necessarily solvable) real algebraic group $G=(S\times T)\ltimes U$
Let $G$ be a connected real algebraic group. I have seen the following two facts:
Based on this notes
1.If $G$ is nilpotent, then $G_s$ is a closed, connected subgroup (hence a torus). $G_u$ is the subgroup of unipotent elements. Elements in $G_u$ and $G_s$ commute. (Then $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $G_s$ is a subgroup of $G$)
2.If $G$ is solvable, then $G\cong  T\ltimes G_u$, where $T$ is some maximal torus.
In general (if $G$ is not nilpotent/solvable), do we have $G\cong (S\times T)\ltimes G_u$, where $S$ is a real semisimple group (or perhaps a subset of semisimple elements), $T$ is a real torus and $G_u$ is the subgroup of unipotent elements? This may not be the precious statement (if not please let me know the correct one). Correct me if I missed something. I believe this is the same as asking the decomposition of $G/G_u$.
